# Is there a variant of emacs org-mode tailored for z/assembler?

Tags: assembly, emacs, mainframe

I'd like to use emacs to develop z/Assembler code in org-mode (I'll worry about the exporting later). The specific needs I can see are:

1. Since "*" starts a z/Asm comment, use a different character ("=", say) to
   identify headers. I've tried `# outline-regexp:[=]+` in "Local
   Variables:" at the start of the file, but without success.
2. I'd
   like to use tab stops at the conventional z/Asm points, but `#
   tab-stop-list:(1,10,16,36,72)` doesn't appear to set the correct tab
   stops.
3. Associated with that, I'd like to associate the "plain tab" state of
   `org-cycle` to `tab-to-tab-stop`. I can't see even how to try that
   through "Local Variables:"
4. Ideally, I'd like a variant of org mode, maybe associated with the
   ".zorg" extension (whatever) which "just made this all happen".

Does anyone know of emacs code do do anything like this?

I am neither an expert in emacs guts, nor Lisp, so please go easy with me -- I dont really know what I'm doing.

If you think this is off-topic, please feel free to migrate it to superuser (though I think it's a better fit here).

Answer (score 1):

You most probably want to check the minor mode `orgstruct-mode` instead of org-mode itself.

Also try changing `org-outline-regexp` instead of `outline-regexp`.

Sadly enough, there is no z/Assembler support for Org Babel yet.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to say, using `org-outline-regexp` doesn't appear to have any effect.